# Not greedy regex does not work

Tags: java, regex

My Regex:

```
\@((TIME|NOW|TODAY)\(.*?\)\s+[0-2]?[0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9])
```

My String:

```
@Time blah blah @TIME(1d) blah @NOW(12312) 12:32:25 blah @TODAY(12312) 12:32:25
```

What I expect to match:

```
@NOW(12312) 12:32:25
```

Comment: If you need to match just `@NOW(12312) 12:32:25`, you only need [`@NOW\([0-9]+\)\s+[0-9:]+`](https://regex101.com/r/nM7nP1/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a negated character class instead of `.*`:

```
@((TIME|NOW|TODAY)\([^@]*?\)\s+[0-2]?[0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9])
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iS0xD9/1)

`[^@]*` will match 0 or more of any character that is not `@` thus not matching any other string starting with `@`.

If there is a possibility of having `@` in your matched string then you can use negative lookahead based regex:

```
@((?:TIME|NOW|TODAY)\((?:(?!@(?:TIME|NOW|TODAY)).)*\)\s+[0-2]?[0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9])
```

[RegEx Demo2](https://regex101.com/r/iS0xD9/2)